# 2LO OAuth support

Tags: google-drive-api

I just read the news about discontinued Document List API with recommended migration to Drive API v2, but there seems to be zero support for 2LO OAuth for Google Apps domains.
What is a recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Service Accounts.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount